# Convert ByteArray to File Object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, arrays

I am trying to take data that I have extracted from a ZIP file in Actionscript, then convert it to a File object so I can write it to the documents folder for my air app to use.

I have the ByteArray data handy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

[FileStream writeBytes documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#writeBytes%28%29)

Believe you can use the class above to write to disk, to give the user the option to browse you can use the file object and it's corresponding browse methods to allow the user to pick a location then using a handler on the select event from the file object have it use the FileStream class to writeBytes to the nativePath of the File object.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question was asked recently regarding the saving of files using the file stream class:

[Performing an auto-save with Adobe AIR with out a popup save box opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411230/performing-an-auto-save-with-adobe-air-with-out-a-popup-save-box-opening/9412486#9412486)

Although the question is different, the answer is still pertinent, containing an example of using the file stream class.